# Python Flask смена хидера на всей структуре

Tags: python, flask, header

Собственно сабж
Как сменить заголовки на отдачу?
Сейчас сервер отдает такие заголовки

Content-Length: 33 Bytes
  Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:2016 Mar 4 19:47:15
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.4 Python/3.5.1

Как можно изменить заголовок у всего проекта, есть решение которое заменяет заголовок у 1 адресса например route('/')
а как сделать что бы возврат сделать сразу у всех методов которые имеются в проекте?
Нужно изменить заголовок Server

Решение

```
    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        resp = flask.Response("Foo bar baz")
        user.weapon = boomerang
        resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        return resp
```

Не понятно для меня, и не особо устраивает, если придется возращать всегда заданный заголовок

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [How do I set response headers in Flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25860304/4279). Если в Вашем случае `app.after_request` работает, то опубликуйте это как [свой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать переопределить класс Responce.

Как пример:

```
class MyResponse(app.response_class):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

app.response_class = MyResponse
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773348/python-flask-how-to-set-content-type)